# Creating an Exact Duplicate Secondary X/Y Axis with imshow

Tags: python

I'm looking to put a secondary axis on my color grid I've created with matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import numpy as np
import struct

colornames = ['LG','MSH','AS','LM','DB','TS','DG']
hexvalues = ['B0AFA6', '988D81', '92909A','976F6F','5E4D43','D1BFA9','2F353F']
pvalues = np.array([[0.20,0.40,0.20,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05]])
rows = 30
cols = 52

for iPDistInd in range(len(pvalues)):
    plt.figure()
    for iSubPlot in [221, 222, 223, 224]:
        ax = plt.subplot(iSubPlot)
        hexdata = np.random.choice(hexvalues,(rows,cols),p=pvalues[iPDistInd])
        rgbdata = [[struct.unpack('BBB',bytes.fromhex(y)) for y in x] for x in hexdata]


        im = plt.imshow(rgbdata, interpolation=None,
                        extent=[0.5, 0.5+cols, 0.5, 0.5+rows])

        plt.grid(True, which='both')
        ax.set_xlim(0,cols+1)
        ax.set_ylim(0,rows+1)
        ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0,cols+1,1))
        ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,rows+1,1))
        ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='green')
        ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='blue')
        plt.suptitle(str(list(zip(colornames,pvalues[iPDistInd]))))
        plt.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0.03, 1, 0.95])
plt.show()
```

But all the documentation I can find on [secondary_xaxis](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.secondary_yaxis.html) and [twinx()](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx.html) coupled with [tick locators](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-locators.html) are focused around creating a *different* axis on the secondary axis. Other stack overflow answers are similar.

**I just want a one-to-one copy of the x and y axes on the 'top' and 'right'.**

Adding

```
        ax2 = ax.secondary_xaxis('top')
        ay2 = ax.secondary_yaxis('right')
```

inside he for loop is closest I can get, but then I'm not sure how to manipulate the x and y ticks such that they match the 'bottom' and 'left' axes.
(Yes, I know the labeling is quite crowded, but once I print to .pdf then there's enough space to read them.)

Any advice?